# How to align 2 equations in a specific way?

Tags: equations, formatting, align

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{align}
p(\theta) = p(\alpha_{j[i]}, \beta_{j[i]}, \mu_{\alpha}, \sigma_{\alpha}, \mu_{\beta}, \sigma_{\beta}, \sigma ) \\
= p\giventhat{\alpha_{j[i]}}{\mu_{\alpha},\sigma^2_{\alpha}} \times p\giventhat{\beta_{j[i]}}{\mu_{\beta},\sigma^2_{\beta}} \times p(\mu_{\alpha}) \times p(\sigma_{\alpha}) \times p(\mu_{\beta}) \times p(\sigma_{\beta}) \times p(\sigma)
\end{align}
\end{center}
```

How can I make it so that the second line of equation (which starts with an equal sign) starts directly under the equal sign from the equation above?

Comment: just ad ampersands before equal sign.  And remove `center` environment around `align`. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks. It did smth but not as I wanted. It shifted but starts after the point where the first equation stopped. But i want it to be shifted to the point where the first equal sign is..

Comment: Off topic: you really shouldn't be embedding display math in the `center` environment.  It only fouls up the vertical spacing above and below the display.  Also, it would be useful for you to read the user guide for `amsmath` regarding proper use of `align` (`texdoc amsldoc`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you not provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document) I can only guess what your document looks and how `\giventhat` is defined. I suppose that `\textwidth` is large enough, that equation in the second line can be fit in text area:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@giventhatstar}[2]{\left(#1\middle\mid#2\right)}
\newcommand{\@giventhatnostar}[3][]{#1(#2#1\mid#3#1)}
\newcommand{\giventhat}{\@ifstar\@giventhatstar\@giventhatnostar}
\makeatother

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
p(\theta) 
    & = p(\alpha_{j[i]}, \beta_{j[i]}, \mu_{\alpha}, \sigma_{\alpha}, \mu_{\beta}, \sigma_{\beta}, \sigma ) \\
    & = p\giventhat{\alpha_{j[i]}}{\mu_{\alpha},\sigma^2_{\alpha}} \times
        p\giventhat{\beta_{j[i]}}{\mu_{\beta},\sigma^2_{\beta}} \times   
        p(\mu_{\alpha}) \times p(\sigma_{\alpha}) \times 
        p(\mu_{\beta}) \times p(\sigma_{\beta}) \times p(\sigma)
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have provided more code. But it worked, thanks!